# How to retrieve output and number of results from find?

Tags: shell, find

I want to make shell script that find some file(s). It should input result in one variable and number of occurrences in another. Now, I made script like this:

```
...
PATH=`find -name $FILE`
NUM=`find -name $FILE | wc -l`
...
```

Flaw is that I am using find command twice for a same search. So I wonder if I could Use one command and populate two variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use you PATH variable in the second assignment:

```
~$ PATH=$(find .)
~$ NUM=$(find .|wc -l)
~$ echo $NUM
32

~$ NUM=$(echo "$PATH"|wc -l)
~$ echo $NUM
32
```

Note that [PATH](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is a variable name that should not be used as it is an internal variable. And that the [`$(...)`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#CSPARENS) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.

Comment: I know, I am using different var name. Here PATH is just for an illustration. And thanks, this does solve mine problem, but I still wonder is there a way to populate two variables with one command?